# How do I import a new PowerShell cmdlet?

Tags: powershell

I've written a PowerShell cmdlet in C#.

Where do I copy the library at this point?

And how do I import it into PowerShell so that I can use it?

Comment: Did you check this article first (and all linked articles) [Writing a Windows PowerShell Cmdlet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878294(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: @Neolisk - Yes. That's how I learned how to write the cmdlet. But I'm not seeing the next step - how to deploy. I'm sure it's there, but I'm not seeing it.

Comment: For what PowerShell version did you write it? Do you have a PSSnapIn derived class in your project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to load your new cmdlet.

1. [Import Cmdlets Using Modules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878307%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Here you either put your cmdlet DLL into a system-recognized path that will allow you to load a module with a simple name (e.g. `Import-Module MyModule`), or you can put it in an arbitrary directory for which you need to specify a complete path (e.g. `Import-Module C:\code\MyModule.dll`). If you have only a single DLL and no dependencies, you can actually give the DLL as shown. Typically, though, you will also want to create a manifest using [New-ModuleManifest](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849709.aspx) (creating, e.g., a MyModule.psd1 file) then pass that psd1 file rather than the dll to `Import-Module`.
2. [Create a Windows PowerShell Snap-in](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714450%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). This requires writing one additional C# class, quite small, that provides the glue necessary to treat your cmdlet as a snap-in. Then you have to register the snap-in with the `installutil` program and finally load the snapin with `Add-SnapIn`. (See also [How to Register Snap-ins...](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714644%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#extendshellusingsnapin))

Curiously, almost all articles that talk about writing cmdlets suggest the snap-in approach, but this is simply because that technique has been available since PowerShell version 1, while modules did not come along until version 2. Everything I have read, though, suggests essentially that the snap-in approach is deprecated to the simpler--and more flexible--module approach.

Comment: Confirmed - modules are preferred unless you must support V1.